# Kafka streams handle batch data to reset aggregation

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have some data arriving in my kafka topic "datasource" with the following schema (simplified for demo here):

```
{ "deal" : -1, "location": "", "value": -1, "type": "init" }
{ "deal": 123456, "location": "Mars", "value": 100.0, "type": "batch" },
{ "deal" 123457, "location": "Earth", "value", 200.0, "type": "batch" },
{ "deal": -1, "location": "", "value", -1, "type": "commit" }
```

This data comes from a batch run, we takes all deals and recalculates their value. Think of it as a day-start process - at this point, here is a fresh set of data for all locations. *At the moment the init and commit messages are not sent to the real topic, they are filtered out by the producer.*

During the day, there are then updates as things change. This provides new data (in this example we can ignore overwriting data, as this would be handled by re-running the batch):

```
{ "deal": 123458, "location", "Mars", "value": 150.0, "type": "update" }
```

This data comes into the application as a KStream "positions".

---

Another topic "locations" has a list of possible locations. These are pulled into a java kafka-streams application as a KGlobalTable locations:

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "Mars" },
{ "id": 2, "name": "Earth"}
```

---

The plan is to use a java 9 kafka-streams application to aggregate these values, grouped by location. The output should look something like:

```
{ "id": 1, "location": "Earth", "sum": 250.0 },
{ "id": 2, "location": "Mars": "sum": 200.0 }
```

This I what I have working so far:

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

/** snip creating serdes, settings up stores, boilerplate  **/

final GlobalKTable<Integer, Location> locations = builder.globalTable(
                LOCATIONS_TOPIC, 
                /* serdes, materialized, etc */
                );

final KStream<Integer, PositionValue> positions = builder.stream(
                POSITIONS_TOPIC,
                /* serdes, materialized, etc */
            );

/* The real thing is more than just a name, so a transformer is used to match locations to position values, and filter ones that we don't care about */
KStream<Location, PositionValue> joined = positions
                .transform(() -> new LocationTransformer(), POSITION_STORE) 
                .peek((location, positionValue) -> { 
                    LOG.debugv("Processed position {0} against location {1}", positionValue, location);
                });

/** This is where it is grouped and aggregated here **/
joined.groupByKey(Grouped.with(locationSerde, positionValueSerde))
            .aggregate(Aggregation::new, /* initializer */
                       (location, positionValue, aggregation) -> aggregation.updateFrom(location, positionValue), /* adder */
                Materialized.<Location, Aggregation>as(aggrStoreSupplier)
                    .withKeySerde(locationSerde)
                    .withValueSerde(aggregationSerde)
            );

Topology topo = builder.build();
```

The problem I have is that this is aggregating everything - so the daily batch, plus updates, then next daily batch, all get added. Basically, I need a way to say "here is the next set of batch data, reset against this". I do not know how to do this - help please!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understood you correctly, you want to aggregate the data, but only for the last day, and discard the rest.

I suggest that you aggregate into an intermediary class that contains all the values in the stream, and also has logic for filtering away the data for the other days. If I understood you correctly, that would be discarding all the data before the last one of type "batch".

Although in Kotlin, I have done a [similar solution](https://github.com/navikt/soknadsarkiverer/blob/ff456a570898ef66642762dd0cc0c5bd0db6994a/src/main/kotlin/no/nav/soknad/arkivering/soknadsarkiverer/kafka/KafkaConfig.kt#L60-L78) that you can look at if you need.

Comment: You do understand correctly. Thank you, I will have a look at this and see if it fits my needs. I am still getting used to streams and topologies 

Comment: The code in my example will count how many ProcessingEvents of type STARTED are on the topic, but it will discard any ProcessingEvents of type FINISHED. It collects the data into an intermediary class called ProcessingEventDto, which has the logic for determining if a ProcessingEvent is finished and is responsible for delivering a count of how many times it was STARTED

Comment: Thank you - I ended up flagging a position to indicate when a reset was required, and using that in the aggregator:
```
if (measurement.dealNum == PositionValue.RESET_FLAG)
   return null;
  else 
   return aggregate.updateFrom(limit, measurement);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things you can do, but I would recommend using a TimeWindowed Stream. You can set the time to a rolling window of 1 day and perform an arrogation on that stream. The you will end up with each day aggregated in its own window in a KTable. Then you will not have to worry about discarding the data (although you can) and each day will be separated.

There are a few good examples of how they work here : https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TimeWindows

Comment: I had considered this, but a day is not always at the same point in time. So today it could reset at 2am, tomorrow 2.05am, etc. I think the overlap could cause problems. Is there such a thing as a programmatic window?

Comment: There are also sessions windows which group records they are split on how much time passes between two records. If the data comes in batches this might work for you

in 2.7 there will also be sliding windows which will maintain the same amount of records in a each window. Al though I don't quite think that this will fit your need as well